# The tank turret does not follow the hull

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-physics, physics

I made a smooth turn of the tank's turret behind the camera along the "Y" coordinate. Now, when my tank runs into some object, the hull of the tank rotates, and the turret on which this code is applied remains in place, according to "Y" it rotates further, and almost does not change along other axes if I during the game through the scene I change the coordinate "X" or "Z", then the tower will smoothly return to the coordinates to zero coordinates along these axes. I do not understand how to do this, the tank turret along the "X" and "Z" axes was the same as that of the tank hull.

```
   public Transform camera;
   public float speed = 50f;

   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
      transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, camera.eulerAngles.y, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
   }
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what your goal is from the text. Maybe restructure your text into "what happens now" and "what do I want to happen". Also some drawings might help

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code a bit and solved my problem

```
transform.localRotation= Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, camera.eulerAngles.y, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
```